# restart loop after it's paused by flag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm putting together some code to essentially replace the contents of a div when I mouseover a specific link.  I then added the changer function to cycle through the content replacement automatically.  I set flags for mouseover and mouseout and I can actually get the changer function to stop on mouseover but I can't quite figure out how to make it start up again on mouseout.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
var pause=false;
$('.banner-nav a').mouseover(function () {
    pause=true;
    setFeature(this);
    return false;
});
$('.banner-nav a').mouseout(function () {
    pause=false;
});
changer(0, 5000);

function setFeature(f) {
    var m = $(f).attr('rel');
    $('.banner-nav a').not(f).removeClass('active');
    $(f).addClass('active');
    $('#featureContainer').html($(m).html());       
}
function changer(index, interval) {
    var buttons = $('.trigger'),
    buttons_length = buttons.length;  
    var button = buttons.eq(index % buttons_length);
    setFeature($(button));
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!pause) {
            changer(++index, interval);
        }
    }, interval)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pause a setTimeout call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626005/), [javascript: pause setTimeout();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/), [Javascript setTimeout function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191769/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `changer` is responsible for its own delayed execution, but pausing it stops the scheduled execution. Another problem is that the next scheduled execution (if any) still happens after pausing.

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Instead of using a flag, clear the interval to pause and start it again to unpause.

```
(function() {
    var index=0;

    function changer() {
        var buttons = $('.trigger'),
        buttons_length = buttons.length;  
        var button = buttons.eq(index % buttons_length);
        setFeature($(button));
        ++index;
    }

    var changerInterval,
        period = 5000;

    function startChanger() {
        if (! changerInterval) {
            changerInterval = setInterval(changer, interval);
        }
    }
    function stopChanger() {
        clearInterval(changerInterval);
        changerInterval = 0;
    }

    $('.banner-nav a').mouseover(function () {
        stopChanger();
        setFeature(this);
        return false;
    });
    $('.banner-nav a').mouseout(function () {
        startChanger();
    });

    /* could implement other functions to e.g. change the period */
    function setChangerPeriod() {
        ...
    }
    window.setChangerPeriod = setChangerPeriod;
    ...
})
```

Comment: Hi outis, thanks so much for your response.  I tried implementing this but I think I must be missing something.  It doesn't seem to fire the changer at all.  I setup a jsfiddle here.http://jsfiddle.net/F855X/2/