# Why is this javascript not running as expected?

Tags: javascript, dom, loops, timeout

```
    function animateGraph() {
    var graph;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        var start = new Date();
        while((new Date()) - start <= 500) {/*wait*/}
        document.getElementById("timeMark").innerHTML = phoneX[i].epoch;

    }
}
```

The loop works. The wait works. But the document.getElement is not showing up until the last item in the array...why?

Comment: It's because synchronous JavaScript blocks the page from being redrawn until it's complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using setTimeout will allow the code to run and not lock up the page. This will allow it to run the code and will not effect other elements on the page.

```
var cnt = 0;
(function animateGraph() {
    document.getElementById("timeMark").innerHTML = phoneX[cnt].epoch;
    cnt++;
    if (cnt<10){
        window.setTimeout(animateGraph,500);
    }
})();
```

Comment: @antonpug run the code youngin and see the magic of setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop, waiting for a datetime, is not a good way to wait - it just blocks execution. It keeps the browser (including UI, and its updating) frozen until the script finishes. After that, the window is repainted according to the DOM.

Use [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead:

```
function animateGraph(phoneX) {
    var el = document.getElementById("timeMark")
    var i = 0;
    (function nextStep() {
        if (i < phoneX.length )
            el.innerHTML = phoneX[i].epoch;
        i++;
        if (i < phoneX.length )
            window.setTimeout(nextStep, 500);
    })();
}
```

Please note that this runs asynchronous, i.e. the function `animateGraph` will return before all `phoneX`es are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout instead of a while loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Also try something like this.
[Javascript setTimeout function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191769/javascript-settimeout-function)

Comment: @antonpug add your settimeout code to the question so everyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet uses a helper function to create the timers. This helper function accepts a loop counter argument `i` and calls itself at the end of the timer handler for the next iteration.

```
function animateGraph() {
    var graph;
    setTimeMarkDelayed(0);

    function setTimeMarkDelayed(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("timeMark").innerHTML = phoneX[i].epoch;

            if (i < 10) {
                setTimeMarkDelayed(++i);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

You actually need some sort of helper function, otherwise you'll end up overwriting the value of `i` in your for loop in every iteration and by the time your timers run out, `i` will already be `9` and all handlers will act on the last element in `phoneX`. By passing `i` as an argument to the helper function, the value is stored in the local scope of that function and won't get overwritten.

Or you could use `setInterval` like Radu suggested, both approaches will work.